# gradient at the corner s only in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient

[image]How can we make grey white gradient effect of gradient on all the four corners of the artwork only not in middle in illustrator.
Like the one created in red marked areas.

Comment: Just use a radial gradient or gradient mesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I do it is by using a single radial gradient and a clipping mask.

Follow the steps:

- Create a rectangle the size of your document and fill it with white or light grey.
- Create a larger rectangle and instead of a color fill, use a gradient with the first bottom gradient slider set to opacity and location 0 and the second bottom gradient slider set to opacity and location 100.
- Double click on the second gradient slider and choose a darker grey.
- Click on the top gradient slider that's in the middle right now and set it to 75 instead of 50.
- Center both rectangles and send the bigger one to back.
- Create a clipping mask (Ctrl+7) and that's all.

[image]

From here on it's up to you to play with the shapes and colors.

Good luck !

Comment: Hey!!! It really works. Thanks alot :) Also can u pls tell me that does this kind of gradient comes out good in printing also???

Comment: Well, it should and it will if the printer itself is good. You won't find any problems with it. Also, if one of us answered your question to your needs, please select one of the 3 answers as the correct one by clicking the checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

Best way I can recommend to do this is create one large box with the base color, then create four triangles in each corner with the gradient. Then group or convert to symbol.

Comment: Seems to be a professional method but a little bit complicated cannot exactly figure out how work out this one. But, anyways thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

- Draw a rectangle and set it the color you want the corners to be.
- Grab the **Gradient Mesh Tool**
- Click *once* in the center of the rectangle
- Change the color
- You can then move the anchor handles to adjust the effect if you wish.

[image]

The gradient is a bit *rough* in the animation **due to the gif format** and a desire to keep image size small. But in reality the gradient will be nice and smooth.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Gradient mesh also seems to be a good method to be applied.